# File move & copy utility that compares files after copying, preferably Total Commander-like

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager, copy, checksums

I particularly like the feature of Total Commander, that while **moving or copying files it can verify whether the files were actually correctly copied and the copies match**. Here is the list of Total Commander alternatives: https://168hours.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/10-total-commander-alternatives-for-linux/ so I decided to give mc (Midnight Commander) a try, partially that I used it in my Xenix times - who remembers Xenix, the Microsoft Unix, now?

Much to my astonishment mc does not an option to automatically compare copied files.

Which one of the other file managers has an **option to compare copied/moved files automatically**?

Comment: does it have to be a file manager? `rsync` does this with the `-c` option. But file managers never use rsync :P

Comment: Oh try http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/

Comment: Hmm, I looked at the screen-shots and cannot find the option to actually move files nor file selector window. How can I mark several files and move them to another location so before Grsync deletes original file it compares it with the copy?